# Change the style of the AutoCorrect context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my wpf app I added a spelling check grammar feature to the text boxes. Everything is working, however my app has a "Dark" theme and the ruling TextBlock Foreground color is white, so when I right click on a word that is misspelled (as denoted by a red squiggly line) the context menu displays all text in white as well. In my DarTheme.xaml ResourceDictionary file I have my TextBlock style as

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlDefaultForeground"  Color="#FFE6E6F0" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultForeground}"/>
</Style>
```

Thinking that all I had to do was set up a context menu style I added the following to this ResourceDictionary file:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultBorderBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

But no matter what I do the text in my context menu always comes up white. What Can I do to fix that. Ideally I would like to see the text change to something like black so its easier to read. Any thoughts on this? By the way this context menu is not in my app (at least I dont think) its something that shows up as part of the spell checking feature I added. I checked for it and at least I didn't create it. Any help will be most appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Did you try to select the context menu text by using the Live Visual Tree to analyze which element is involved and then try to analyze which resource or style is involved?

Comment: *What Can I do to fix that?* Do not define an implicit `TextBlock` style (without an `x:Key`) globally.